# How to deal with multiple csv.gz files in Spark?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, compression, apache-spark-sql, gzip

I have a huge dataset with multiple tables. Each table is split into hundreds of csv.gz files and I need to import them to Spark through PySpark. Any idea on how to import the "csv.gz" files to Spark? Does SparkContext or SparkSession from SparkSQL provide a function to import this type of files?

Comment: `sc.textFile` will work but it will give you an RDD with one partition for each file you read sicne `gzip` is not a splittable compression codec.

Answer (score 1):

You can import gzipped csv files natively using `spark.read.csv()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("stackOverflow") \
        .getOrCreate()

fpath1 = "file1.csv.gz"
DF = spark.read.csv(fpath1, header=True)
```

where `DF` is a spark DataFrame.

You can read from multiple files by feeding in a `list` of files:

```
fpath1 = "file1.csv.gz"
fpath2 = "file2.csv.gz"
DF = spark.read.csv([fpath1, fpath2] header=True)
```

You can also create a "temporary view" allowing for SQL queries:

```
fpath1 = "file1.csv.gz"
fpath2 = "file2.csv.gz"
DF = spark.read.csv([fpath1, fpath2] header=True)
DF.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")

DFres = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table_name)
```

where DFres is a spark DataFrame generated from the query.